# Maven 3.0.4 fails to deploy but Maven 3.0.0 works fine

Tags: maven, maven-3, nexus

I have a simple Maven project set up that can deploy to a local Nexus server.  All the relevant configuration elements are in place (`<distributionManagement>` section with URL, `<server>` element in my settings.xml file with username and password, etc).  I know the setup is correct, because on Maven 3.0, I can deploy.  On Maven 3.0.4, I have two problems.

If I try to deploy with 3.0.4 out of the box, I get a `handshake_failure`.  As far as I can tell, this is because 3.0.4 [switched backing HTTP clients](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-http-settings.html).  I have included the server CA's certificate in a truststore pointed to by `javax.net.ssl.trustStore` in my `MAVEN_OPTS` environment variable, along with a client cert in a keystore specified by `javax.net.ssl.keyStore`, [as instructed](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-repository-ssl.html).  Again, this works on 3.0.  For some reason, it's not being picked up by the new HTTP client.

So, I tried dropping the `wagon-http-lightweight` JAR into the `lib/ext/` directory for 3.0.4, which brings me to my second problem: once I force the use of the `lightweight` client, I stop getting `handshake_failure` and start getting HTTP 401.  Again, the username and password work under Maven 3.0.  It's clearly picking up the username, because running with `-X` includes the line "

I've been wrestling this for hours now and I've hit a dead end.  I'd welcome a solution, but I'd also welcome any suggestions for my next move here.

Comment: Update: I swapped out the `wagon-http-lightweight` JAR I had been using, which was version 2.2, with a version 1.0 JAR.  Now, deploy works again.  After noting this, I tried 2.0 and 2.1.  2.1 fails, 2.0 succeeds.  I guess it's a bug introduced in 2.1 and still present in 2.2?  I'm off to check if it's been reported....

Comment: You might be using an unsupported config for the new wagon in terms of url or so. Care to share your distributionManagent details?

Comment: I have a similiar issue, but with no SSL involved. Just following a URL redirect causes the problem. Reported here: https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/WAGON-421

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would recommend:

- Upgrading to 3.0.5 which is now out and has many SSL-related fixed, with the upgrade of the faulty wagon.
- Reading:

  - The [Maven 3.0.4 Release Notes](http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.0.4/release-notes.html). The 3.0.4 ones describe the changes regarding the httpclient.
  - The [Maven 3.0.5 Release Notes](http://maven.apache.org/docs/3.0.5/release-notes.html). This has a vague explanation, but if you follow things closely, you will find out that:

    - [MNG-5430](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNG-5430) Upgrades the version of the Wagon. That, in term, means that the [SSL support which is broken in 3.0.4](http://jira.codehaus.org/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10335&version=18697) is fixed.
  - [The Maven Guide to HTTP Settings](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-http-settings.html). These reflect the above mentioned changes and I'm sure will solve your problems.